# Парсинг JSON в PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json, vue.js, axios

Отправляю на серв данные c помощью [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) в JSON. Форма генериться с помощью VueJS.

```
axios.post(this.form.action, this.form.model) ну и т.д.
```

В this.form.model у меня значения полей формы в виде key => value.

```
{"props[color]":[110,109],"props[size]":[113]}
```

При отправке на сервере получаю

```
["props[color]"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(109)
    [1]=>
    int(108)
  }
  ["props[size]"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(113)
  }
```

Как можно получить вид

```
[
    'props' => [
        'color' => [],
        'size' => []
    ]
]
```

Т.е. на клиенте при отправке мне нужно чтобы вместо

```
{"props[color]":[110,109],"props[size]":[113]}
```

было

```
{props: {color: [110,109], size: [113]}}
```

Пробовал распарсить с помощю регулярки ключи, но банально не хватает знаний как это сделать правильно.

```
let dataKeys = {};
let keyRegex = /[^\[\]]+|\[\]/g;

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => { 
    dataKeys[accumulator] = [currentValue]
};

Object.keys(this.form.model).map(key => {
    console.log(key.match(keyRegex).reduce(reducer))
});

console.log(dataKeys); // {"props":["size"]}
```

П.c.: возможно есть вариант проще как скормить название модели вроде props[color] VueJS которое он сам распарсит правильно.

Comment: Непонятно что и в каком виде вы отправляете. Эти строки не похожи на JSON

Comment: как вы это отправяете то?

Comment: Сорри, обновил вопрос.